# Xcode 15.3 wont let me use run destination of other simulators but the newest 17.4, even though I have 17.2 installed

Tags: xcode, xcode15

so I was running my program fine on Xcode, now it updated to xcode 15.3 automatically, and I can't run anymore because it is saying I dont have the 17.4 installed. (Which a different issue but I cannot install 17.4).

[Here is a picture of the platform 17.2 showcasing it is already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXu2c.png)

[THis is the image showing I have a simulator for Iphone 15 with the IOS I have installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unj8t.png)

[And here is the image showing that no other simulators are shown besides 17.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rDut.png)

I am really unsure what to do, because I cannot dowload IOS17.4, I am using intel Mac 2019.

I just want to be able to run my code on the simulator it was already working fine, but for some reason no other simulator appears in the list for run destinations.

I have tried going to Product -> Destination -> Show all destinations, and still only the 17.4 appears.
I have tried creating a néw simulator with 17.2 IOS which is installed, but I can néver dowload and run the builds. it always say it is néeding IOS 17.4